# Less code in Tabbed Eventlistener

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm writing a code for a simple bottom navigation bar in Xamarin. I have 2 elements in my navigation that respectively contains an icon and some text. When one is tabbed, the colors of both elements are changed.

```
void Tutorials_Tabbed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var page = new Tutorials();
    PlaceHolder.Content = page.Content;
    //Change color
    TutView.Foreground = Color.FromHex("#318ce7");
    TutTxt.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#318ce7");

    CalcView.Foreground = Color.Gray;
    CalcTxt.TextColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

Same goes for the method that controls the other navigation bar element.

Currently, I think it seems like overkill to write 4 lines of code to do this relatively simple task. 
- Therefore I'm asking you if this can be optimized in any way?

Answer (score -1):

2 lines :)

```
TutView.Foreground = CalcView.Foreground = Color.FromHex("#318ce7");
TutTxt.TextColor = CalcTxt.TextColor = Color.Gray;
```

Comment: It seems no fun allowed on stackoverflow :(